# How can we use DOJO from CDN in OpenSocial App?

Tags: dojo, opensocial

How can we use DOJO from CDN in OpenSocial App?

Answer (score 2):

Can it be done in OpenSocial Apps? From [Frequently Asked Questions – OpenSocial](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/faq.html):

> What other JavaScript libraries can I use?
>
> All of them! Dojo, Prototype, JQuery, GWT, etc.

As you can see Dojo is mentioned explicitly.

You can include it using a script tag in your HTML snippet as regular Dojo. The only difference is that modules are loaded asynchronously — [it is covered in the docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/cross-domain.html#quickstart-cross-domain).

Comment: Do you have any sample which elaborates a little bit on this?

Comment: OpenSocial tutorials cover how to use HTML snippets. Just add a proper script tag there before another script with your custom JavaScript code. One example can be found here: http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Improving_Latency